# Track User Login Session using HttpSessionBinding Event

Tags: java, session, servlets

I want to track user session to check for multiple logins by same user

The execution of my web app is as follows

In the below **ServletContextListener** I am initializing a **java.util.Set** to store all the active users and I am setting it to a ServletContext object so that it should be available to the whole web app

```
@WebListener
public class InitilizationClass implements ServletContextListener {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public InitilizationClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)
     */
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)
     */
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Setting initialization parameters");
        Set<ActiveUser> allusers = new HashSet<ActiveUser>();
        ServletContext sc = arg0.getServletContext();
        sc.setAttribute("logins", allusers);
    }

}
```

Below is my **Servlet** code. When user enters a username and password, the username is set to the **ActiveUser** class which is a **HttpSessionBindingListener**. A HttpSession is initialized to store the ActiveUser object in session.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("pass");

                             ActiveUser user = new ActiveUser();
                             user.setUserName(username);
                             HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                             if(session.isNew())
                             {
                                 session.setAttribute("userlogged", user);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 session.setAttribute("userlogged", user);
                             }

    }
```

Now the setAttribbute in the above **Servlet** will invoke the valueBound method in the below class. In this method if the Set is empty the ActiveUser object will be added to the Set. But if it is a second login by the same user with same credentials it should just display message as "User already logged in with name (its username)".

```
public class ActiveUser implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    private String username = null;
    private String password = null;

    public void setUserName(String uname)
    {
        this.username = uname;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ServletContext sc = arg0.getSession().getServletContext();
        ActiveUser session = (ActiveUser) arg0.getSession().getAttribute("userlogged");
        Set<ActiveUser> user = (Set<ActiveUser>) sc.getAttribute("logins");
        if(user.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("A user session has been created");
            user.add(session);
            sc.setAttribute("logins", user);
        }
        else
        {

            for(ActiveUser users : user)
            {
                System.out.println("Names "+users.getUserName()); // Null Pointer Exception
                if(session.getUserName().equals(users.getUserName()))
                {
                    user.remove(users);
                    System.out.println("User already logged in with name "+users.getUserName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on line

```
System.out.println("Names "+users.getUserName());
```

on **second login**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(ActiveUser users : user)
            {
                System.out.println("Names "+users.getUserName()); // Null Pointer Exception
                if(session.getUserName().equals(users.getUserName()))
```

I think it is more probable that the line

```
session.getUserName().equals(users.getUserName())
```

is the one throwing NPE. That is because the valueBound method will be called when any attribute is added to the session, not just the attribute you are looking for. So check for your specific attribute

```
 public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
      String attr = (String)arg0.getValue();
      if("userlogged".equals(attr){
               //do your stuff here
      }
 }
```

A couple of other things not related

1. The below code makes no sense

> if(session.isNew())
>                                {
>                                    session.setAttribute("userlogged", user);
>                                }
>                                else
>                                {
>                                    session.setAttribute("userlogged", user);
>                                }

2. This technique will never work if the application is deployed in a cluster.